# Formula for integral over hypersurface??

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, manifolds

Can someone give me a formula for an (Lebesgue) integral of a function $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ where $M$ is a bounded $C^k$-hypersurface of dimension $(n-1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

I have tried the following:

---

since $M$ is a $C^k$ hypersurface, there are open covers $U_i$ such that $U_i \cap M = \{(x,g_i(x)) : x \in D_i \subset \mathbb{R}^{n-1}\}$ is the graph of a $C^k$ function $g_i\colon \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}.$

Then
$$\int_M f = \sum_{ i}\int_{D_i}f(x,g_i(x))dx$$

---

But I think this is wrong. It seems intuitivelty right to me though. Please can someone give me the correct formula.